# Adjacency Matrix for User in R

Tags: r, matrix, binary, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I have a data as follows -

```
user_id     post_id
24376261    204506440
98461       204446324
98461       203026202
98461       203031838
311542      204351465
875740      203031838
```

This data indicates that posts on which a user has comment in a website's article/post.
Now, I need to create  a matrix with user_id in rows and columns and values will be 1 if these users are connected through a blog post else 0. i.e the output I want will look like this -

```
user       24376261 98461   311542  875740
24376261    1       0       0       0
98461       0       1       0       1
311542      0       0       1       0
875740      0       1       0       1
```

How can I do this in R? I tried following Brian method from this question - [Adjacency matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419507/adjacency-matrix-in-r?rq=1)
But I get an R object of the following class -

```
> class(am)
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
```

How can I convert this into a data.frame or something that can be exported to R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that gets you your desired output:

```
tcrossprod(table(mydf))
#           user_id
# user_id    98461 311542 875740 24376261
#   98461        3      0      1        0
#   311542       0      1      0        0
#   875740       1      0      1        0
#   24376261     0      0      0        1
(tcrossprod(table(mydf)) != 0) + 0
#           user_id
# user_id    98461 311542 875740 24376261
#   98461        1      0      1        0
#   311542       0      1      0        0
#   875740       1      0      1        0
#   24376261     0      0      0        1
```

If you want the result as a `data.frame`, you can wrap the output in `as.data.frame.matrix`.

---

This is assuming that "mydf" is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(user_id = c(24376261L, 98461L, 98461L, 98461L, 
311542L, 875740L), post_id = c(204506440L, 204446324L, 203026202L, 
203031838L, 204351465L, 203031838L)), .Names = c("user_id", "post_id"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't give me the same result as yours. Can you tell me what is in the mydf table?

Comment: @RHelp, ***you're*** the one that is supposed to be providing a reproducible example, not the person answering. Nevertheless, I've added an update with what I used as "`mydf`".

Comment: I have added my data in my question. And thanks for your patience. But this doesn't work on my data set. If I try you solution, I get useri_id and post_id in my rows as well as my columns and all values filling the matrix are 1 in all combinations.

Comment: @RHelp, you pasted a *view* of your data, not anything that tells us the structure of your data. Use `dput` to share your data in a reproducible manner.