# Converting a nx1 matrix to a nxn square matrix

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I have asked a similar question before but this is slightly different compared to my previous question.

I have a matrix

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  1  1  0
b  1  0  1  1  1
```

I am trying to convert this to a square matrix like this

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  1  1  0
b  1  0  1  1  1
c  1  1  0  0  0
d  1  1  0  0  0
e  0  1  0  0  0
```

Any advise on how to do this in r will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RStudent thanks for helping. I found the answer,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419507/adjacency-matrix-in-r?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about this solution?

```
res <- (merge(m, t(m)[(nrow(m)+1):ncol(m),], all = TRUE, by = 0:2))[,-1]
rownames(res) <- colnames(res)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```