# structural holes and adjacency matrix

Tags: r

I am working on a problem to find the measures related to structure holes in R. The problem is that when I apply the code below to save the adjacency matrix to a variable called "x"  (copied from that source) [Adjacency matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419507/adjacency-matrix-in-r) 
it gives me an error like:

> "Error in as.data.frame.default(d) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""igraph"" to a data.frame"

My code and data set looks like this 
a data frame

```
s1
   uid1 uid2    
1     1    2    
2     1    3    
3     1    4    
4     1    5    
5     2    3   
6     2    4    
7     2    5    
8     3    4    
9     3    5    
10    4    5   
11    6    7    
12    6    8    
13    6    9    
14    7    8    
15    7    9    
16    8    9    
17    1    6   
18    1    7   
19    6    7
```

When I apply this code then the error becomes over here

```
x <- get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(s1), directed=F)))
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(d) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""igraph"" to a data.frame

So any help to use this code for the structure holes measure like

```
y <- index.egonet(x) #desired output is this code
```

Comment: You're going from a data.frame to a matrix to an edgelist to a graph. Just go data.frame --> graph. `x <- get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(s1, directed=F))`

Comment: yep it works  but when i apply this code it give me this error now                        index.egonet(x)
Error in intI(i, n = d[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  invalid character indexing

Answer (score 0):

You are going

```
data.frame (s1)               -->  
   matrix                     --> 
     graph via graph.edgelist --> 
       trying to create a graph again via graph.data.frame
```

And that's why you're getting an error, because you already have a graph, and `graph.data.frame()` expects a `data.frame` as input, not an `igraph` object. That's what the error message is saying:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(d) : cannot coerce class ""igraph"" to a data.frame

I.e - "don't give me an 'igraph' object, I want a data.frame"

The end conclusion of all this is - just go from your source `data.frame` to an `igraph` object, then extract the adjacency matrix:

```
get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(s1, directed=F))
```

Comment: your above suggestion is working but when i apply      index.egonet  to the adjacency matrix (X) it gives me an error.like       index.egonet(x)                                                                                                  Error in intI(i, n = d[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  invalid character indexing