# R cast can't deal with unique rows

Tags: r, casting, grouping, dcast

**Question**

---

I have `cluster.id` and corresponding to these cluster.id's I have the different `letters` found in each cluster (as simplification). 
I'm interested in which letters are generally found together over the different clusters (I used the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430883/r-update-adjacency-matrix-data-frame-using-pairwise-combinations)), however I'm not interested in the proportions wherein each letters is found, so I wanted to remove duplicated rows (see code below).

This seems so work (no error) however the cast matrix gets filled with `'NA'` and strings instead of the desired counts (I explain everything further in the code comments below).

Any suggestions how to fix this problem, or is this just something that isn't possible after filtering for unique rows?

**Code**

---

```
test.set <- read.table(text = "
                            cluster.id   letters
                       1          4       A
                       2          4       B
                       3          4       B
                       4          3       A
                       5          3       E
                       6          3       D
                       7          3       C
                       8          2       A
                       9          2       E
                       10          1       A", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)



# remove irrelevant clusters (clusters which only contain 1 letter)
test.set <- test.set %>% group_by( cluster.id ) %>%
  mutate(n.letters = n_distinct(letters)) %>%
  filter(n.letters > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select( -n.letters)

test.set
#  cluster.id letters
#<int>   <chr>
#1          4       A
#2          4       B
#3          4       B
#4          3       A
#5          3       E
#6          3       D
#7          3       C
#8          2       A
#9          2       E



# I dont want duplicated rows becasue they are misleading.
# I'm only interested in which letters are found togheter in a 
# cluster not in what proportions
# Therefore I want to remove these duplicated rows

test.set.unique <- test.set %>% unique()
matrix <- acast(test.set.unique, cluster.id ~ letters)

matrix
#  A   B   C   D   E  
#2 "A" NA  NA  NA  "E"
#3 "A" NA  "C" "D" "E"
#4 "A" "B" NA  NA  NA 


# This matrix contains NA values and letters intead of the counts I wanted.
# However using the matrix before filtering for unique rows works fine

matrix <- acast(test.set, cluster.id ~ letters)
matrix
#  A B C D E
#2 1 0 0 0 1
#3 1 0 1 1 1
#4 1 2 0 0 0
```

Comment: `table(test.set)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we also look at the messages, there would be a message above the output

> Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

In order to get similar output, specify the `fun.aggregate`

```
acast(test.set.unique, cluster.id ~ letters, length)
#  A B C D E
#2 1 0 0 0 1
#3 1 0 1 1 1
#4 1 1 0 0 0
```

When there are duplicate elements, by default the `fun.aggregate` is triggered for `length`.  With `unique` elements, without specifying the `fun.aggregate`, it will assume a `value.var` column and fill the values of that column to get the output as in the OP's post